# Browserify doesn't works in Docker container

Tags: django, docker, browserify

I'm setting up my project and i set browserify to works with my front end assets and refresh the browser.

For the back end i'm using django, so, i made a proxy between both for works in the same time:
**gulfile.js**

```
// Start a server with BrowserSync to preview the site in
function server(done) {
  browser.init({
    // server: PATHS.dist, //port: PORT
    proxy: 'localhost:8000',
    notify: false
  });
  done();
}
```

But it doesn't works when i rise up the project with composer, simply doesn't show me anything when i rise up composer:

```
sass_1           | [BS] Proxying: http://localhost:8000
sass_1           | [BS] Access URLs:
sass_1           |  -----------------------------------
sass_1           |        Local: http://localhost:3000
sass_1           |     External: http://172.18.0.7:3000
sass_1           |  -----------------------------------
sass_1           |           UI: http://localhost:3001
sass_1           |  UI External: http://172.18.0.7:3001
sass_1           |  -----------------------------------
sass_1           | [BS] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
```

It works fine when i rise up since my computer, without using Docker, but in docker it can open my browser and i can't get into `3000` port.

I got the same problem with `django-debug-toolbar`, but i solved it putting the internal ips got from `docker` configuration.

I tried changing the port inside `gulpfile` by the `ips gateway`(solution for before bug) but doesn't works.

My `docker-composer` file is:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: uzman
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - npm
      - bower
      - sass
      - migration
      - db
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/tmp/data/
  npm:
    image: uzman
    command: npm install
    volumes:
      - ./uzman/static:/code/uzman/static
    working_dir: /code/uzman/static
  bower:
    image: uzman
    command: bower install --allow-root
    volumes:
      - ./uzman/static:/code/uzman/static
    working_dir: /code/uzman/static
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:latest
    command: elasticsearch -Enetwork.host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
  sass:
    image: uzman
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./uzman/static:/code/uzman/static
    working_dir: /code/uzman/static
  migration:
    image: uzman
    command: python manage.py migrate --noinput
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `browserify` doesn't running in the same time, for these reason is not possible get access to it.

So expose the ports for browserify:

```
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
  - "3001:3001"
  - "8000:8000"
```

And execute `npm`:
`docker exec -it uzman_web_1 bash -c "cd /code/uzman/static; exec npm start"`

It's all.